# OnSelectionChanged Need More Of An OnStyleChange - JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I am building a simple WYSIWYG editor, many out there are way to complex to integrate, or does not give the user good feedback.

I can do what I want with the OnSelectionChanged event, but that seems to be too wide of a net, the event fires more often than I want/need. What I would like is an event that fires if say the font changed, or bold changed at the current cursor location.

for example, if I have a line of text "this has a **BOLD** in the lin^e" and the cursor is at the '^', then click or move the cursor towards the word Bold, I do not need the event to fire until it hits the word that is bolded, or other change (text color, size, style...).

Currently, in the event code, it calls the queryCommandState, and looks to see what parts of the toolbar buttons become highlighted, in this example the "B" gets highlighted, when it hits Bold, just like a normal text editor, like Word.

My concern with the round trip time, looking for a couple of things is not bad, but when I look at all the formatting, (bold, underline, size, color, style...) it starts to add up. I thought about putting an escape hatch in, but it still needs to go through and look at what is the current values and then compare it to the last state, so I do not gain anything.

Is there a better event option than the one i am using, such as some kind of stylechanged event, or an event that fire when it sees a tag change.

Thanks,

Dave

Comment: Dave, I posted an answer that basically says you're trying to solve the wrong problem and I'm not being cheeky. Can you offer any more insight as to why building the editor seems easier than including a prebuilt one?

Answer (score 0):

I think that you should revisit your premise that integrating a wysiwyg editor is way too complex and that building one is a reasonable alternative.

I've included one js file from a cdn and added this single line of javascript to transform a textarea into a rich text editor, with nice visual feedback regarding formatting options.

```
CKEDITOR.replace('editor1');
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/GyWGvY

Comment: I have used CKEditor, TinyMCE, and others. I just got a site up using CKEditor, but had to dig deep into the code to make it all work, such as image uploads, had to change the paths, I had to really shoehorn that code. it is like I had to build my project around that editor. Somethings did not work well, such as copy and paste from say Word.

Comment: Also I am not doing this from "line 1", I am trying to bring openWYSIWYG from openwebware to a nicer user feedback GUI. That project is slick, one JS file, and easy to use, it just does not have any user feedback, and want to add a couple of other functions.Has not been updated since 2006-07 so had to take out the browser check function, so it would run in Edge and such.